# How to add field on standard report type?

Tags: reporting

I have a custom field (Checkbox) which needs to be added on "Leads" and "Leads with Converted Information" standard report types.

Can anyone explain me how to do that?

Comment: When you add fields to a standard object such as Leads, they are automatically added to the Standard Report Type.  With that being said, you may still need to add them to the Reports that use those report types.  If so, just go into the Report, customize it, and add the field where it needs to go.

Comment: @JamesLoghry Why didn't you just add it as an answer?

Comment: I bizarre 'feature' I have just noticed is that if Custom Fields are NOT in the Page Layout, they are NOT available in the Standard Report Type... I can't see the logic in that...

Answer (score 6):

When you add fields to a standard object such as Leads, they are automatically added to the Standard Report Type. With that being said, you may still need to add them to the Reports that use those report types. If so, just go into the Report, customize it, and add the field where it needs to go.

For custom report types, it's slightly more work. Simply go into Setup->Create->Report Type, click the Selected Fields button and add the field.

To answer your questions in your comment:

1. You can't modify standard report types with the exception of adding new fields to the sobject and having them listed on the report type.
2. There's no sure fire way of running a "report of reports" and adding a single field per record type.

Here are a few ways you could potentially group reports by report type:

1. Have a separate folder for each Report Type.
2. If that doesn't work for you, then you may have to look into customization.  For instance, in Apex and Visualforce, you could query the Report object and group reports by report type.  From here you could either provide links into the report type, providing a useful but tediuous UI for updating the reports, or you could go even crazier with calling the Metadata API and update all the reports with the new field.

Comment: Yeah.. Slightly modifying my question..
How do we make a custom field a default field on a particular report type so that it can reflect on all the reports which come under that particular report type at the time of creation of that field itself? 
If we can't make a default field on report types...then my next question is...How do we see all the reports of my org which comes under a particular report type, so that I can go ahead and add a field on all reports at One-go?

Comment: @Arshad updated my answer to reflect your new questions.

Comment: @JamesLoghry did you ever get to the bottom of the issue, I  too am unable to see a particular custom check-box field listed in a standard "Opportunity" report type.

Answer (score -1):

You can't modify standard report types with the exception of adding new fields to the sobject and having them listed on the report type.: HOW???

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question or its other answer for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL).